# Python Webscraping - Error Object of type Response is not JSON serializable when extracting data

Tags: python, json, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am performing web scraping in via Python \ Selenium \ Chrome headless driver which involves submitting a POST request, which in turn returns data in JSON which I need to extract data from.  Here is my code:

```
  payload = {'JobId': '123456'}
  r = requests.post('https://mywebsite.com/customTransactionRecordRest/getTransactionRecordHeaderDetails', data=payload)
  print(r.status_code)

  driver.get(r)

  soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
  if not "Page Not Found (404)" in soup.find("body").text:
    dict_from_json = json.loads(soup.find("body").text)

  try:
    Amount = (dict_from_json['nextPaymentTransactionRecord']['amount'])
  except: Amount = "Unknown"
```

However, it errors at this line:

```
driver.get(r)
```

With the error message:

```
Error Object of type Response is not JSON serializable when extracting data
```

How do I extract the data from the JSON when sending a POST?

I can achieve this when performing a GET but not a POST.  I do get a 200 response from the website so everything looks ok.  I am logging into the website in previous steps and creating a session.

Comment: Mind sharing the URL?

Comment: Have you tried to print the response and verified that it's valid JSON?